# How to disable the Symfony translation for specific bundles

Tags: symfony, internationalization, translation, symfony-2.7

I am creating a webapp running with Symfony 2.7, which is designed to be used only with one language (a unique locale). I can see in profiler many missing messages in every translation domain, but I don’t need translation at all.

How can I disable the translation component?

**Edit :**
What if I want to keep translation for some bundles, and disable it for others bundles ? For instance, I have Sonata Admin Bundle, and I want to keep using it in with its translation, but I don't want Symfony to look for translation messages with other bundles.

**Edit 2 :**
So I guess it's not possible to disable translation only for one of my own bundle ?
I still have missing translation messages warning in the profiler.

Comment: just comment line contains `translator` in config http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/translation.html#configuration

Comment: Which bundles? In your own bundles, simply don't use the translator

Comment: Yes, it concern my own bundles. How to do that ?

Answer (score 27):

You can disable translation by configuration. Edit **app/config/config.yml**

```
framework:
  translator:
    enabled: false
```

Comment: Thanks, but what if I want to disable translation only for some bundles in particular ?
For instance, I have Sonata Admin Bundle, and I want to keep using it in with its translation, but I don't want Symfony to look for translation messages with other bundles.

Comment: FrameworkBundle is a "configuration manager" for each symfony's component. You can enable or disable component only at all.

Comment: When you disable the `translator` the translator service still is available. The only difference we notice when disabling the framework translator is that the `profiler toolbar` translation panel isn't available anymore. Probably because adding the `data collector listener` has a higher priority.

Comment: It's not a true answer, I want just disable notice not translator

Answer (score 1):

to disable translation logger set this in `config/packages/translation.yaml`

```yaml
framework:
  translator:
    logging: false
```

see the reference for the translator section in FrameworkBundle's Configuration: https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html#translator